# How do I prevent vertical scrolling of a table containing long text?

Tags: css

Our build software has a web interface that reports build status using a table.  When a build is pending, it outputs the last log message in an inner table.  These log messages can be very, very long.

This is a distilled version of the HTML emitted:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="StatusGrid" class="SortableGrid">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="buildstatus">
        <td colspan="11">
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>hello</td>
                <td>...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

If you display this HTML in your browser, you have to vertically scroll to see the entire contents of the table.  I don't want this.  I *never* want the table to extend outside the vertical width of the browser window.  I don't mind truncating/clipping the extra-long text in the inner table.

I tried `word-break: break-all`, but that only works in Chrome.  **I have to support IE 9 and the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox.**

The final wrinkle: **I have to use CSS to fix this**.  I only have access to the application's stylesheet, and not the HTML.

What do you think?  Possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a fixed height on the td and set its overflow or overflow-y to hidden;

```
tr.buildstatus td{
   height: 500px;
   width: 600px;
   overflow:hidden; /* or overflow-y:hidden; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.  You may have to adjust height/width to your taste.

```
tr.buildstatus tr td + td {
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:600px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/R8nmk/

Answer (score 0):

Try `overflow: hidden`.
The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible.
More about overflow [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).